# Call all the same named methods in one line

Tags: java, game-engine, lwjgl

I want to make stuff like "behavioural logic" in my game engine (written in Java SE), but I failed to make one, hence I don't know how to make sure that all the subclass methods are called automatically. It will work similar as Unity3D's behaviours (like Update(), Start()...), but for logic. Here I supply my trial of achieving it

```
public abstract class Behaviour {
     void Start(){}

     abstract void Update(){}

}
```

this class is inherited by DaturaBehaviour class

```
public class DaturaBehaviour extends Behaviour{

public void AppInit()
{
    Start();
    System.out.println("foo");
}

public void AppRun()
{
    Update();
    OnGUI();
}

}
```

from where I defined the methods which will be called (AppInit method for example in engine initialisation, AppRun in every frame drawn).

So these are the basis on this system. I made a test class also:

```
public class TestBehaviour extends DaturaBehaviour {

@Override
void Start()
{
    System.out.println("bar");//this isn't called dunno why
}
```

}

This is my first attempt to make games with Java, so please, don't be furious, if this is a obvious stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I don't know how to make sure that all the subclass methods are called automatically
```

You have to know what you call and which parameters you use in your methods. At some point in your code you have to manually write which methods and which order you want to call.

EDIT :

Ah, I probably know what you think about. This is way how to do it :

```
private class Something {
    public void yeah() {
        System.out.println("");            
    }
}

private class Something2 extends Something{        
    @Override
    public void yeah(){
        super.yeah();
    }
}
```

EDIT2 : Ok, this is just guessing, but I think what you probably want is this :

```
private static abstract class Animal{
    abstract void sound();       
}

private static class Dog extends Animal{
    @Override
    void sound() {
        System.out.println("haf");
    }        
}

private static class Cow extends Animal{
    @Override
    void sound() {
        System.out.println("mooooo");
    }
}


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
    animals.add(new Dog());
    animals.add(new Cow());
    animals.add(new Dog());
    animals.add(new Dog());
    animals.add(new Dog());
    animals.add(new Cow());
    animals.add(new Cow());
    animals.add(new Cow());
    animals.add(new Dog());
    animals.add(new Cow());
    animals.add(new Dog());
    animals.add(new Dog());
    animals.add(new Cow());
    animals.add(new Dog());
    animals.add(new Cow());
    animals.add(new Dog());
    animals.add(new Dog());

    for (Animal animal : animals){
        animal.sound();
    }
}
```

Output :

```
haf
mooooo
haf
haf
haf
mooooo
mooooo
mooooo
haf
mooooo
haf
haf
mooooo
haf
mooooo
haf
haf
```

Comment: I know, that I want to call, hence you see the AppInit, which will (but does not) call the subclass method what I plan to override, without parameters. The problem that the example above does not work, I gave it as insight how I want to make it, but it fails unfortunately :(

Comment: Well then you have to be more specific in what exactly you trying to achieve and where exactly it does not work as you think it should.

Comment: I am trying to call for example Start() once and all the subclasses will automaticly call the Start() method (but only if they have the Start() method overridden)

Comment: Well I think I figured it, checked out edited answer :)

Comment: well, close enough, but in the extended class I want to define the behaviour of that object and call from the superclass, so your answer is okay, but I want the exact opposite of it :D (call yeah from something and that will trigger automatic calls of subclass yeah methods)

Comment: It is not possible in any language, cause it is illogical. Superclass does not know nothing about extended classes. Try to think, that you have superclass Animal and extended class Cow and Dog. You create instance od cow, dog and animal. Of course, cow and dog knows that they are animals and they can call "sound()", but if you create "animal" (I suppose it is not abstract), what it should do with sound()? Call both "haf" and "moo"? It does not make sense :)

Comment: But Unity3D does this same thing in C# what I want, but I don't know how do they manage this :/